# Push notification over my phone dosen't work in my home only

Tags: wi-fi, push-notifications

I have an android phone that doesn't notify me with any events and or updates whatever it is in my home only. while when I use the "Data Connection" over 3G or when I use any open WiFi it notify me simply with no problem at all.

I thought it is a modem Issue. my modem is a Dlink modem and I tried to restart it but still facing this problem

Any Idea will be so greatfull.

Edited Information:
My phone is Infinix zero 2 running Android 4.4.2

Comment: Might be an issue with your WiFi router, more specifically ports blocked/firewall. Though I've never experienced that, and I didn't open any ports for that specifically. Are you using any firewall app or permission manager on your device?

Comment: @beeshyams I have just edited my question with the mobile model and android version

Comment: @Izzy I am sure it is an issue with my WiFi router, but I don't know what is the problem is? and how to solve it.and no I am not using any firewall nor any permission manager on my device.

Comment: To further narrow it down: Can you find out if it's only happening with *your* WiFi – do you have a chance to try it in some other WiFi at a friends/relatives house? Also, any chance to access the router's logs?

Comment: @Izzy its only happening with my WiFi . it notify me with other WiFi with no problem at all. But of course i cant access any others router log, except mine of course.

Comment: OK, in that case it's not related to Android, but rather a "networking issue" related to your router. And of course you only need the log from the router "breaking it".